# Get and Save a File in .NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

This question is more a 'best practice' one  essentially regarding web api get/post methods and especially around idempotence when designing APIs.

I have a web api GET method that needs to retrieve a file and then save it accordingly.
In pseudocode form what I have is this:

```
   //File Service Class  
    public async Task<Document> GetFileAsync(string id)
    {
        var file = await GetFileFromStorageAsync(id);
        //then save file. 
        _repository.SaveFileAsync(file);

    }

    //Controller Class 

    public async Task<ActionResult<Document>> GetAsync(string Id)
    {
        var result = await fileService.GetFileAsync(Id);
        if(result != null)
        {
            return OK(result);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that I have a Save action in a 'Get' Method. This is often frowned upon.
given the above scenario, what would be best practice ? I've attempted to refactor the code and just only get the file and then add extra logic in the controller 'get' method to then call the Save method after, but that seems like almost same as I have now since essentially we are still calling a 'SAVE' in a 'GET' method.

I would say this is more an edge case but what other approaches can one use to  keep side effects to a minimum when designing API's?

Comment: Why are you saving the file in the `GetFileAsync` method? You should just be returning the `file` object in that method (or mapping it to the return type). As a consumer I would not expect to call the `GetAsync` controller method and have a file saved so unless there is an internal reason it seems unnecessary. Even if it was necessary internally then `FileService` should expose a `GetFileAndSaveAsync` method to make the workings clear to internal consumers.

Comment: The pseudo code makes no sense. 1) `GetFileAsync` retrieves a file and immediately saves the file. 2) `GetFileAsync` does not await the save operation. 3) `GetFileAsync` does not return anything. 4) `GetAsync` only returns something when the result is not null.

Comment: Best practice would change the name of the api endpoint from `get` to something that represents what's actually occurring: retrieves a file, modifies the file, and then sends back the modified file. In other words, this is not a get operation; this is a modify operation. Also, the entire purpose of the Controller is to assemble everything; if that includes retrieving, then modifying, then resaving, then just do it in the Controller.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I understand there are some omissions with the code above, but this example was more to show that whilst the method primarily does a '"get" , it also does a save afterwards which as you say may not be best practice , hence my question.